# how to push selected item to top in listview android

Tags: android, android-listview

I have around 5 views in my listview and I want to push the selected view to top of the listview(set the position 0) and move down rest of the views. For example my views go like this from top to bottom

1-2-3-4-5

when I select the third one then I want the listview be like this:

3-1-2-4-5 but of course their last position id must be in order such 1-2-3-4-5

Comment: swap the selected position with the first position then notify the adapter that the data changed

Comment: A thing you can do, look trough all your elements and recreate these elements after replacing them. Load them into a list, and on the first position you insert the clicked element.

Comment: I know I need to swap it but how? u dont have any direct code to swap a listview items

Comment: I added an answer to the question, it shows how you can load all child buttons ( you should change this ) into a list ( don't forget to change the type of the list too, it's written inside the <> characters ). After that, I'm removing the views and adding them back one by one. :) First inserting the clicked element and also skipping the element in the loop! I haven't tried it so it's a guess on the go.

Answer (score 0):

I made you a small example how you can reorder your list, please note that this only works for buttons ( you can just change the cast to a View if you are moving entire views. Also, this only works on one button for now, but you can change that easily!

```
Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // create a new list
        ArrayList<Button> list = new ArrayList<Button>();
        ScrollView view = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrollView1);

        // add your clicked element on position 0
        list.add ( (Button) arg0 );

        for ( int i = 0; i < view.getChildCount(); i++ ) {
            if ( view.getChildAt(i) != arg0 ) {
                list.add( (Button) view.getChildAt(i));
            }
        }

        view.removeAllViews();

        for ( int x = 0; x < list.size(); x++ ) {
            view.addView(list.get(x));
            list.remove(x);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks it works but i have a little issue which is  that when I click on a position twice it does push up the only first view I clicked on

Comment: did you add the listener to every button? If not, it won't work. If you aren't using a button, you might want to set a listener to the elements you are using ( layouts or what so ever ).

Comment: If this solution is the right one, please mark it as an answer so other people don't waste their time by writing one. :)